# Python: How to extract only the year-month-day from dataframe

Tags: python

The *date* column from the data frame *df* is in this format:

> 2018-12-20 19:30:00

But I want to create a column that will only contain the dates without the time

> 2018-12-20

How should I extract the dates only?

Comment: you can split it by space and get the first element

Answer (score 1):

You can use .dt function

```
 df['just_date'] = df['date_&_time'].dt.date
```

The above returns a datetime.date dtype, if you want to have a datetime64 then you can just normalize the time component to midnight so it sets all the values to 00:00:00:

```
df['normalised_date'] = df['dates'].dt.normalize()
```

This keeps the dtype as datetime64 but the display shows just the date value.